# How do I add a click eventlistener to select an option from the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create an input field where I can add in custom tags as well as tags from a suggestion list. How do I add a click event listener to one of the suggestions to select it and create the tag as this is something that is dynamically created in javascript?

```js
const stackSuggestionDiv = document.querySelector('.stack-suggestion-div');
const stackSuggestion = document.querySelector('.stack-suggestion');
const searchStack = document.querySelector('#search-stack');

searchStack.addEventListener('input', function(stackTag) {
    const input = searchStack.value;
    stackSuggestionDiv.innerHTML = '';
    const suggestions = stackTags.filter(function(stackTag) {
        return stackTag.toLowerCase().includes(input);
    });
    suggestions.forEach(function(suggestion) {
        const suggestionDiv = document.createElement('div');
        suggestionDiv.setAttribute('class', 'stack-suggestion');
        suggestionDiv.innerHTML = suggestion;
        stackSuggestionDiv.appendChild(suggestionDiv);
        input.value = '';
    });
    if (input === '') {
        stackSuggestionDiv.innerHTML = '';
    }
    
});
```

```html
<div class="tech-stack-input-suggestion">
          <div class="tech-stack-bar">
            <div class="tech-stacks-input">
              <!-- <div class="stack-tag">
                 <span>Ruby on Rails</span>
                 <i class="material-icons">close</i> 
               </div> -->
             </div>
              <input type="text" id="search-stack" class="create-stack-input" placeholder="Enter Teck Stack" autocomplete="off"/>
              <i id="arrow-down-btn" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
        </div>
        <div class="stack-suggestion-div">
          <!-- <div class="stack-suggestion">React.Js</div>
          <div class="stack-suggestion">React.Js</div> -->
        </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): First introduce the problem, then post the relevant code/[mcve]

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What problems do you have with your approach?

Comment: you have got too much code going on here. start with a simple drop down list.